# What is a good descriptor for similar objects?

Tags: image-recognition, computer-vision, feature-selection

I am developing an image search engine. The engine is meant to retrieve wrist watches based on the input of the user. I am using SIFT descriptors to index the elements in the database and applying Euclidean distance to get the most similar watches. I feel like this type of descriptor is not the best since watches have a similar structure and shape. Right now, the average difference between the best and worst matches is not big enough (15%)

I've been thinking of adding colour to the descriptor, but I'd like to hear other suggestions.

Comment: Why are you using SIFT?  Have you tried deep learning?

Answer (score 2):

How to develop a program that can sort images by similarity is similar to the problem of how to develop a program that can sort words by how similar they look.

For example:
"theory" is more similar to "teoryyy" than to "abc".

What determines similarity of two words or images are these factors:

- how many parts are common to both images
- how many parts are new in either image
- how many parts are missing in either image
- how many parts are zoomed in/out or stretched.
- how many parts are displaced

There may be some other rules. By combining these rules you can explain how similarity recognition works. This is at the core of intelligence.